# Can we alter the All_objects table with the Sys user?

Tags: oracle

can we alter the all_objects table with the sys user.
can i alter it using the alter command.
or is this table read only?

I was looking into the tables and tried to alter it,but for some reason
im not able to do it.Is it coz it can only be read.

Comment: Are you sure it is a table and not a view?

Comment: Why would you want to alter it? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

ALL_OBJECTS is a view it is based primarily on internal table SYS.OBJ$.
NEVER alter in any way the internal tables or views of the database dictionnary.
What are you trying to achieve by altering this view?

Comment: I was looking for the owner of an object.Are the contents in the owner column alterable ?